# Orbit Installation Using Luarocks in Windows

Tags: model-view-controller, lua, luarocks

I am trying to install **Orbit MVC web Framework** for **Lua**,using the command **luarocks install orbit** . But it always returns the following error :

*Installing http://www.luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/orbit-2.2.4-1.src.rock... Using http://www.luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/orbit-2.2.4-1.src.rock... switching to 'build' mode                                                                                                                                            Error: Failed unpacking rock file: C:\Users\BANEE-~1\AppData\Local\Temp\luarocks_luarocks-rock-orbit-2.2.4-1-6500/orbit-2.2.4-1.src.rock*

I am using Windows 7 64 bit professional edition with lua 5.1.5 and luarocks version 2.0.10. Both lua and luarocks in path and accessible globally. **How to resolve this error** or is there **any other way to install a package using luarocks**?

Comment: May be you have problem with internet? I just install it on my system with all deps (xavante, orbit, cosmo etc.)

Comment: No, the net connection is working and i tried several times - always returns this error. i think it is the problem with my old luarocks. and i tried to update the version, it results the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329860/luarocks-installation