# Luarocks Installation

Tags: lua, luarocks

I am trying to install the latest version of Luarocks, obtained from [luarocks's official site](https://luarocks.org/). Firstly, I used the Lua binaries obtained from [LuaForge Lua Binaries project](http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/) referred from [Official Lua site](http://www.lua.org/). But the install script returns the following error (trailed output because of stack overflow restrictions) :

```
LuaRocks 2.4.x installer.

========================
== Checking system... ==
========================

Admin privileges available for installing
Looking for Lua interpreter
    checking C:\Programs\Lua
       Found lua.exe, testing it...
Interpreter found, now looking for link libraries...
    checking for C:\Programs\Lua\lua5.3.lib
    checking for C:\Programs\Lua\lua53.lib
    checking for C:\Programs\Lua\lua5.3.dll
    checking for C:\Programs\Lua\lua53.dll
       Found lua53.dll
....................................................
Could not find Lua. See /? for options for specifying the location of Lua, or installing a bundled copy of Lua 5.1.

Failed installing LuaRocks. Run with /? for help.
```

Then I used another Lua binaries obtained from [Lua - joedf's Builds](http://joedf.ahkscript.org/LuaBuilds/) referred from [Official Lua site](http://www.lua.org/). But the install script returns the following error (trailed output because of stack overflow restrictions) :

```
LuaRocks 2.4.x installer.

========================
== Checking system... ==
========================

Admin privileges available for installing
Looking for Lua interpreter
    checking C:\Programs\Lua
       Found lua53.exe, testing it...
Interpreter found, now looking for link libraries...
    checking for C:\Programs\Lua\lua5.3.lib
    checking for C:\Programs\Lua\lua53.lib
    checking for C:\Programs\Lua\lua5.3.dll
    checking for C:\Programs\Lua\lua53.dll
       Found lua53.dll
Link library found, now looking for headers...
    checking for C:\Programs\Lua\include\lua\5.3\lua.h
    checking for C:\Programs\Lua\include\lua53\lua.h
    checking for C:\Programs\Lua\include\lua5.3\lua.h
    checking for C:\Programs\Lua\include\lua.h
    checking for C:\Programs\Lua\lua.h
    checking C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv
       Found lua53.exe, testing it...
Interpreter found, now looking for link libraries...
    checking for C:\Programs\Lua\lua5.3.lib
    checking for C:\Programs\Lua\lua53.lib
    checking for C:\Programs\Lua\lua5.3.dll
    checking for C:\Programs\Lua\lua53.dll
       Found lua53.dll
......................................................
Could not find Lua. See /? for options for specifying the location of Lua, or installing a bundled copy of Lua 5.1.

Failed installing LuaRocks. Run with /? for help.
```

Then I used another Lua binaries obtained from [LuaDist](http://luadist.org/) referred from [official Lua site](http://www.lua.org/). It already includes luarocks, but an older version. Using this version results the following error : [Orbit Installation Using Luarocks in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328251/orbit-installation-using-luarocks-in-windows). So, tried install script of luarocks. The installation is successful, and I configured the following variables according to the installer instruction (trailed output because of stack overflow restrictions) :

```
............................................................ 
============================
== LuaRocks is installed! ==
============================

You may want to add the following elements to your paths;
Lua interpreter;
  PATH     :   C:\Programs\Binaries-LuaDist-batteries-0.9.8-Windows-x86\bin
  PATHEXT  :   .LUA
LuaRocks;
  PATH     :   C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks
  LUA_PATH :   C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\lua\?.lua;C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\lua\?\init.lua
Local user rocktree (Note: %APPDATA% is user dependent);
  PATH     :   %APPDATA%\LuaRocks\bin
  LUA_PATH :   %APPDATA%\LuaRocks\share\lua\5.1\?.lua;%APPDATA%\LuaRocks\share\lua\5.1\?\init.lua
  LUA_CPATH:   %APPDATA%\LuaRocks\lib\lua\5.1\?.dll
System rocktree
  PATH     :   c:\programs\binaries-luadist-batteries-0.9.8-windows-x86\\bin
  LUA_PATH :   c:\programs\binaries-luadist-batteries-0.9.8-windows-x86\\share\lua\5.1\?.lua;c:\programs\binaries-luadist-batteries-0.9.8-windows-x86\\share\lua\5.1\?\init.lua
  LUA_CPATH:   c:\programs\binaries-luadist-batteries-0.9.8-windows-x86\\lib\lua\5.1\?.dll

Note that the %APPDATA% element in the paths above is user specific and it MUST
be replaced by its actual value.
For the current user that value is: C:\Users\Banee-Ishaque-K\AppData\Roaming.
```

But luarocks command now returns

> windows can't open this file

error, what will do? I am working on Windows 7 64 bit and there is no compilation method for Windows for manual compilation of Lua instead of using binaries.

Comment: I tried http://training-course-material.com/images/1/11/Installing_LuaRocks.pdf . but, bad luck.

Comment: It seems the trimmed outputs are missing critical parts that show what exactly didn't work. Could you link to the full outputs, perhaps pasting them in a service such as http://gist.github.com ?

Comment: Here is the gist you requested @ Hisham H M : https://gist.github.com/Baneeishaque/32281d9222c036075ce0158314ea0f17

Comment: @HishamHM It looks like luarock detection isn't finding `lua.h`. If the length and content of that gist is true, it looks like there are multiple lua interpreters/runtimes scattered everywhere throughout the system. I suggest deleting all of those out and just clean. Have a single lua location where rocks can reliably find it.

Comment: Also what C compiler do you have setup? Are you using mingw or msvc (`cl.exe`)?

Comment: msvc, tried mingw too...

Comment: Can you please provide me the steps to install lua and luarocks in windows 7 64 bit. or how to compile and install and them ( if it is no binary distribution)?@greatwolf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution is, just specify the Lua installation directory to Luarocks Installation script(INSTALL.bat) file using CMD line argument /LUA. In the above case,

```
C:\Programs\luarocks-2.4.2-win32>install.bat /LUA C:\Programs\Binaries-LuaDist-batteries-0.9.8-Windows-x86
```

will install Luarocks successfully. *Tested & Verified on Win 7 64 bit with Lua 5.1 64 bit along with Luarocks 2.4.2 win32 package.*

**To Install Luarocks; Lua interpreter,link libraries,headers & runtime must be present in the system.** The binaries from  [LuaForge Lua Binaries project](http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/) & [Lua - joedf's Builds](http://joedf.ahkscript.org/LuaBuilds/) only contains Lua interpreter & link libraries. That's why the first two methods failed with errors.

Lua binaries obtained from [LuaDist](http://luadist.org/) contains Lua interpreter,link libraries & headers; The runtime will be available in most windows systems used for development purpose (if not, we can install matching ( version that is used to compile Lua source to binary) Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables from Microsoft website). But, the problem is ..\Binaries-LuaDist-batteries-0.9.8-Windows-x86\bin is in path. the folder contains only Lua interpreter. link libraries & headers are in ..\Binaries-LuaDist-batteries-0.9.8-Windows-x86 folder.

Comment: Don't add PATHEXT .LUA. It causes `windows can't open this file` error. I don't know why it happens.

Comment: I tried [Luarocks](https://luarocks.org/) installation using existing LuaRocks in [LuaDist distribution](http://luadist.org/). But, no success. 
 
`Srf@SRF-PC C:\Users\Srf
$ luarocks install luarocks
Installing http://www.luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/luarocks-2.4.4-1.src.rock...
Using http://www.luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/luarocks-2.4.4-1.src.rock... switching to 'build' mode

Error: Failed unpacking rock file: C:\Users\Srf\AppData\Local\Temp\luarocks_luarocks-rock-luarocks-2.4.4-1-330/luarocks-2.4.4-1.src.rock`

Comment: I tried with **LuaRocks 2.4.4. Now - bad argument #1 error occurs and above solution is not working with LuaRocks 2.4.4**

Comment: I wonder how to install or use that 2 exe files from luarocks-3.1.3-windows-32.zip from http://luarocks.github.io/luarocks/releases/

Comment: use luarocks binary exe file, just extract exe file to any folder, and add that folder to your path variable.