# How can I install lua modules/libraries via Lua Rocks?

Tags: lua, installation

I installed JSON library and use it with `require`, now I want to install a date/time library but it says I have to install it through *Lua rocks*. I searched about this but no results after all

Date/time library link: https://github.com/daurnimator/luatz

I downloaded `luarocks.zip` and clicked on install.bat, opened it in my terminal, now I got a new challenge:

```
========================
== Checking system... ==
========================

Admin privileges available for installing

Looking for Lua interpreter

    checking C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Compressed\Cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\Scripts

    checking C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Compressed\Cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5

    checking C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Compressed\Cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu

    checking C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath

    checking C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath

    checking C:\Windows\system32

    checking C:\Windows

    checking C:\Windows\System32\Wbem

    checking C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

    checking C:\Program Files\GtkSharp\2.12

    checking C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Compressed\Lua53

       Found lua53.exe, testing it...

       Error: interpreter does not work

    checking c:\lua5.1.2

    checking c:\lua

    checking c:\kepler\1.1

Could not find Lua. See /? for options for specifying the location of Lua, or installing a bundled copy of Lua 5.1.

Failed installing LuaRocks. Run with /? for help.
```

Answer (score 1):

First, install the package manager Luarocks.
Instructions for:

[Windows](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Installation-instructions-for-Windows)

[MacOS](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Installation-instructions-for-macOS)

[Linux or other Unix](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Installation-instructions-for-Unix)

Next, open your terminal/command prompt.
Type `luarocks install luatz`

You should be able to immediately require luatz using `local luatz = require "luatz"`

Comment: i tried to download lua rocks, but it when I clicked on install.bat, it shows up an error:

Comment: @BlaztOne Can you post the error code? I really can't help without seeing the error. But my suggestion would be to try running install.bat from command line instead of just clicking it. I don't know if that would help but it's something you could try before you post the error code.

Comment: i posted the error code behind ":". Everything after ":" is the error code

Comment: check my question, i edited it. I added the error code

Comment: Does your \downloads\compressed\lua53 folder have other files around the .exe that might look like lua53.dll or do you have a full Lua install somewhere else? I've taken a quick peep at some other peoples' error codes and it looks like there should be a 'found interpreter, looking for linked libraries' block. After confirming your Lua installation is complete, I would recommend running the command `install.bat /LUA C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Compressed\Lua53` in the directory your install.bat is. (hat tip to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329860/luarocks-installation)

Comment: C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Compressed\luarocks-master>rem=rem --[[--lua
LuaRocks 3.0.x installer.


========================
== Checking system... ==
========================


Admin privileges available for installing
Looking for Lua interpreter
    checking C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Compressed\Lua53
       Found lua53.exe, testing it...
       Error: interpreter does not work
Could not find Lua. See /? for options for specifying the location of Lua, or installing a bundled copy of Lua 5.1.

Failed installing LuaRocks. Run with /? for help.